# Uninstall Windows 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I Installed Ubuntu 18.04(LTS)  alongside Windows 10 (Dual Boot), and now I want to uninstall (Delete) Windows 10 from my laptop. I have seen many ways to delete Ubuntu , but none to Delete Windows 10.

Any Help would be most appreciated.

Zuli

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I tried using the Disk Partitioner before and ended up Deleting Ubuntu... so every little step explained would be appreciated... Im a complete novice

Answer (score 0):

I would use the gparted live usb, to: 1. delete windows partition(s), 2. increase size of ubuntu partition(s)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,, my answer would be the same as above

Comment: you download gparted iso from the page. use the startup disk creator in ubuntu, enter bios to start from usb, and do as in disk partitioner without deleting ubuntu.